# Grunt phpcs Warning: spawn ENAMETOOLONG when use watch for file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, gruntjs

I recently started to use grunt to help automate some coding tasks.  I would really like to implement the phpcs (PHP Code Sniffer) module but I'm experiencing errors with trying to get it to work.

My dev workstation is a Windows 7 64bit OS.  I have Node.js installed as well as Grunt and the Grunt CLI.

This is the phpcs config from my grunt file.

```
    phpcs: {
        theme: {
        src: '**/*.*'
        },
        options: {
            bin: "vendor/bin/phpcs --extensions=php ",
            standard: "WordPress-Core"
        }
    },

    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: '**/*.js',
            tasks: ['jshint'],
        },
        php: {
            files: '**/*.php',
            tasks: ['phpcs'],
        },
        css: {
            files: '**/*.css',
        },
        lr: {
            options: { 
                livereload: true 
            },
            files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.php', '**/*.css'],
        }
    },

});
```

When I run grunt and then change a php file I get the following

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "header.php" changed.
Running "phpcs:theme" (phpcs) task
Warning: spawn ENAMETOOLONG Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Completed in 2.422s at Tue May 19 2015 09:57:21 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
 - Waiting...
```

I've tried to use fenestrate to shorten the paths, but that didn't help.  I moved my project directory out of my dev wordpress install and closer to the root of my drive, but that didn't help even with fenestrate.

I'm not sure what path the ENAMETOOLONG warning is complaining about.  I would really like to get this working to help improve my code.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it may be related to PHP_CodingSniffer not being fully installed.  I cannot get a list of installed coding standards.  It never prints anything to the screen, I just get the command prompt back.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that PHP_CodeSniffer wasn't loading the standards that I had downloaded, as well as the default standards.

While trying to load the standards I wanted in, I saw that the path was ending at

```
c:\program
```

when it should have been

```
c:\program files (x86)\php\v5.6\pear\php\CodeSniffer\Standards
```

I had originally installed PHP using the Windows Platform Installer.  So I ended up removing my PHP install.  Downloaded PHP 5.6 again and unzipping to a folder off of the root of C: and then re-installed pear and re-installed PHP_CodeSniffer and now it's working in my grunt file.  It's processing all of my PHP files and not just the one that changes, but it's at least working.